# Valid geoJson not populating Google Maps markers

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, google-maps

The markers associated with my geoJson are not populating on my map. If I run my geoJSON on http://geojsonlint.com/ it all works fine. If I swap my geoJSON with a sample from the google maps dev api `'https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json'` Their overlay populates on my map just fine.

Below I'm running `http://localhost:3009/murals.json` as the argument for `loadGeoJson` I've also tried running `test.json` from a local file.

My map .js

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.0172679,-105.2839094);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'), myOptions
  );
  map.data.loadGeoJson('http://localhost:3009/murals.json');
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize());
```

My controller (no doubt could be refactored, but is outputting the properly formatted geoJSON)

```
def index
    @murals = Mural.all
    muralHash = []
    @geojson = { type: "GeometryCollection",
      geometries: muralHash
    }
      @murals.each do |mural, myHash = {:type => nil,:coordinates => nil}|
        myHash["type"] = 'Point'
        myHash["coordinates"] = [mural.longitude, mural.latitude]

        muralHash << myHash
      end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @geojson }
    end
  end
```

geoJSON

```
    { "type":"GeometryCollection",
      "geometries":[
        {
          "type":"Point",
          "coordinates":[-105.287685950293,40.0124034482671]
        },
        {
          "type":"Point",
          "coordinates":[-105.196297724738,39.9935339839196]
        },
        {
          "type":"Point",
          "coordinates":[-105.283136923804,40.0162490232761]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: please post the JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the JSON is not valid(valid related to the format expected by the maps-API), this would work:

```
{
  "type":"FeatureCollection",
  "features":[
    {
      "type":"Feature",
      "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[-105.287685950293,40.0124034482671]
      }
    },
    {
      "type":"Feature",
      "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[-105.196297724738,39.9935339839196]
      }
    },
    {
      "type":"Feature",
      "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[-105.283136923804,40.0162490232761]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That is not working for me. Also when I run it in the geoJSON linter it fails.

Comment: Had to jerry-rig my code a bit to get that in there for now, but it's running. I take it that trusting that geoJSON linter was a bad move?